# Difference between Mate installation packages

Tags: 18.04, mate, ubuntu-mate

In some instructions explain that to install Mate Desktop in Ubuntu 18.04, we must execute:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

Others mention:

```
sudo apt install mate-desktop-environment
```

Or:

```
sudo apt install mate-core
```

And some more...

```
mate-desktop-environment-extras mate-dock-applet mate-applets
```

What is the difference between these packages and what is the correct way to install them, as the case may be? (comparing the results with Ubuntu Mate 18.04 distro, minimum and complete installation)

**Important:**

Due to the comments, I consider that I should add the following clarifying information:

Ubuntu Mate is a distro that is supposed to contain all the elements of the Mate desktop, however this is not true.

It includes: ubuntu-mate-desktop, mate-dock-applet, mate-applets, mate-desktop-environment-core

Does not include: mate-core, mate-desktop-environment-extras (This package includes: mate-desktop-environment)

It is because of this madness, that, in my opinion, the method of installing Debian (choosing which desktop we are going to work with) I think should be the standard, to avoid these problems (like the one I describe in my question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `ubuntu-mate-desktop` is a comprehensive suite of software packages that will get the MATE environment up and running on your Ubuntu installation.
- This includes many applications that are NOT part of MATE per-say but give you an overall useful environment to work in. Things like office productivity, web browser, games, etc.
- `mate-desktop-environment` is a limited suite of software packages that MATE can integrate with nicely.
- `ubuntu-mate-desktop` includes most, if not all, of `mate-desktop-environment`.
- `mate-desktop-environment` does not include the non-MATE related/integrated components of `ubuntu-mate-desktop`.
- `mate-core` is the bare bones MATE installation.
- `mate-desktop-environment` and `ubuntu-mate-desktop` will include most of the packages from `mate-core`
- `mate-desktop-environment-extras`, `mate-dock-applet, and` mate-applets` are a small selection of software to make MATE reasonably user friendly.
- They are not necessarily included in `mate-desktop-environment` and `ubuntu-mate-desktop`.
- They would be considered optional extras that add visual, integration and usability tweaks in addition to the basic requirements of the `mate-desktop-environment` and `ubuntu-mate-desktop` packages.

You can find out exactly what each package mentioned above would install on your system by running `apt install -s` followed by the appropriate package name.  The `-s` is a *simulation* of what would happen. There's not much point in listing each and every component here, partly because the output would depend on what is already present on your system.

Comment: Your explanation is good but confusing in the last part and you use too many anglicisms and not a common language.

Comment: removed the 'bells and whistles'.

Comment: Give some examples of the use (and installation) of these packages, to better understand your response. Thank you

Comment: @DKBose Thank you for the correction. Good contribution. I tried apt install -s mate-desktop-environment, within Ubuntu Mate 18.04 (since Ubuntu Mate is a distro contains all Mate Desktop packages), and simulates the installation, therefore, I think the phrase "ubuntu-mate-desktop includes mate-desktop-environment" is incorrect

Comment: @DKBose Now there is another package. What is the difference between mate-desktop-environment and mate-desktop-environment-core?

Comment: @DKBose In that you are right. I also use VMs to avoid this. Thanks for your help. the subject is closed

Comment: The complete MATE desktop environment is available from *task* package  - install it with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^` or `sudo tasksel install ubuntu-mate-desktop`.

Comment: You would probably like to add `mate-desktop-environment-core` (minimal Mate desktop installation) :)